# AppDelegate - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm a total Newbie to iOS programming and need to [quickly] port a Cordova application to iOS. I have encountered the error below while trying to replicate a project found [here](http://geospatialscott.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html).

What could be the cause and how can I solve it without going deep into the code? (If possible)

```
AppDelegate getCommandInstance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance <instance>
ebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the     
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:   
<NSInvalidArgumentException> -[AppDelegate getCommandInstance:]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance <instance>
```

Thanks.

[Edit]

AppDelegate.h has the lines below

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;
```

AppDelegate.m has

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

and

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[Edit]

This is the only portion of code that refers to getCommandInstance, which is mentioned in the error as can be seen above. This snippet is found in SQLitePlugin.m

```
-(CDVPlugin*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
self = (SQLitePlugin*)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
if (self) {
    openDBs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [openDBs retain];

    CDVFile* pgFile = [[self appDelegate] getCommandInstance: @"org.apache.cordova.file"];
    NSString *docs = [pgFile appDocsPath];
    [self setAppDocsPath:docs];

}
return self;
```

}

Comment: post line that causes crash.

Comment: Please see edit for code that is referenced at crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you simply should cast your application delegate from base class to the one from your project. For example, if this line causes crash

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] getCommandInstance: someVar];
```

and your application delegate is, for example, `MyAppDelegate`, then just add cast

```
[((MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) getCommandInstance: someVar];
```

of course, in case of your own application delegate implements this method.

Answer (score 0):

First your question is unclear but i assume that is should be

On **AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

On **AppDelegate.m**  I'm **NOT** sure but you may be write as

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

It is wrong so, you need to change as like  this

```
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Comment: Please see the edit above. No line in AppDelegates.m that says self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

Comment: @user2609731 - then where is your rootViewController ?

Comment: I seem to have none. I have added the code as recommended above though, but it hasn't fixed the error. I may have added in the wrong place. I added to AppDelegate.m after self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;